# Group By or Pivot with a filter

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

Here's a Table

```
A |  B |  C ...
1 |  D1|  x  
1 |  D2|  x
1 |  D3|  x
2 |  E3|  x
2 |  D1|  x
3 |  G5| Null
3 |  E3|  x
```

I want to group by Column A and filter out all 'groups' with a Null in Column C in one DataFrame, and get all the 'groups' with the Null in Column C in another Dataframe.

Thank You

Comment: What are you going to do after grouping the data? What's your desired output?

Comment: I got the output I was looking for with a filter. I just needed help with the null syntax. Thanks for all who contributed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `filter` within a `groupby`

Assume the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        A=[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
        B=['D1', 'D2', 'D3', 'E3', 'D1', 'G5', 'E3'],
        C=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, np.nan, 6]
    ))
df

   A   B    C
0  1  D1  1.0
1  1  D2  2.0
2  1  D3  3.0
3  2  E3  4.0
4  2  D1  5.0
5  3  G5  NaN
6  3  E3  6.0
```

Then:

```
df.groupby('A').filter(lambda x: x.C.notnull().all())

   A   B    C
0  1  D1  1.0
1  1  D2  2.0
2  1  D3  3.0
3  2  E3  4.0
4  2  D1  5.0
```